# Xpath sibling condition (or)

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to find the first `preceding-sibling` of a node with OR condition.
For example , i have a node `A` and i try to get the first preceding-sibling `B` but if there is no `B` then get first preceding-sibling`SPAN`.

I don't know how to do the OR condition:
This is what i tried :

```
A//preceding-sibling::B|SPAN[1]
A//preceding-sibling::B[1]|SPAN[1]
A//preceding-sibling::B[1]|preceding-sibling::SPAN[1]
A//(preceding-sibling::B[1]|preceding-sibling::SPAN[1]) // Xpath invalid
A//preceding-sibling::(B|SPAN)[1] // Xpath invalid
.... and many more
```

In short I'm looking for :  Node -> `preceding-sibling::NodeType1[1]` OR `preceding-sibling::NodeType2[1]`

Is there a way to achieve this with Xpath or i must try one and if there is no result try the other ?

EDIT:

The good answer to this question is I think StuartLC answer (I didn't try it).
If you are looking for the first node between `B` and `SPAN` then used har07 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way instead :

```
A//preceding-sibling::*[name()='B' or name()='SPAN'][1]
```

Comment: It might be what you were looking for, but it's not what you asked for. If this finds a SPAN before it finds a B, it will return the SPAN, whereas you said you wanted the B.

Comment: @Michael Kay you are right but that's my fault, my question is not correct. that's the answer I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

As per Michael's comment, note that `*[name()='B' or name()='SPAN']` will return the first `preceding-sibling` which is either `B` or `SPAN`.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to 'fallback' to `SPAN` only IFF there are no `B` `preceding-sibling`s of `A` at all. AFAIK you will need to repeat the query with a union:

```
(A/preceding-sibling::B[1] | A/preceding-sibling::SPAN[1])[1]
```

Comment: I think your answer is good and exactly what i asked but not what I wanted. My English is not good enough I guess. Sorry. I will update my question to avoid confusing your answer and  
har07 answer

Comment: Ok, got it :) Hopefully folk stumbling onto this post will understand!